# JDBC error after application runs for a while

Tags: java, jdbc, jruby

MySQL Connector/J (version 5.1.6) gets me the following error after a few minutes of opening and closing connections every second):

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/someQueue
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:154)
    ...
```

The code is simply:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url, this.connectionProperties);
```

Where `this.url` is the URL found in the stacktrace, and `this.connectionProperties` is:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("user", "root");
props.put("password", "root");
```

I tried fixing it doing it the old way, and adding the following right before the `DriverManager.getConnection(...)` :

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

But it didn't help. Anyone?

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Are you creating a new Connection for every query?

Comment: Yes, I just wanted something that works for now, no complexity. I also want to know why I get this exception ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JRuby version 1.6.0_RC2 was the problem.
Even though it wasn't actively used in the JDBC code, I'm loading a script when I launch my app.

The bug affecting the JDBC drivers can be found here: [JRUBY-5528](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-5528?focusedCommentId=258423)

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly off-topic, but is there a reason you can't use a connection pool? This will save you the overhead of creating a new connection each time. Check out [Commons-DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) for a library which will work (there are examples in the documentation).

Comment: You beat me to it. Though I do not think it is off topic. If there is an application that is opening and closing a connection about every second, a connection pool is very very good suggestion.

Comment: No reason at all, I just wanted something basic first. I added most of the code so you can have a look. Thanks!